# NullPointerException from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets, nullpointerexception, objectinputstream

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I amtrying to get an `Object` through `ObjectInputStream` via a `Socket`. I am using a server to send information to the client (android phone) through a `TransferObject`. I know the server is sending the `Object` because when it sends an error it is read fine and throws no exceptions. All sent classes are serializable, contain a serialVersionID, and are contained in both projects.

code:

```
TransferObject data = null;

try {
    Socket s = new Socket();                                        
    s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT), 10000);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    send.setUser(useremail);
    send.setPassword(password);

    oos.writeObject(send);
    oos.flush();

    Object inputObject = ois.readObject();   //Error happens here.
    data = (TransferObject) inputObject; 

    s.close();
    return data;
}
```

and here is `TransferObject`:

```
public class TransferObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = *******************L;  //blanked this out

    public String command;
    public String args;
    public Object[] objects;

    private String password;
    private String user;

    public TransferObject() {
    }

    public TransferObject(String command, String args, Object[] objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
        this.args = args;
        this.command = command;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And lastly, the dreaded log:

```
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): Process: com.********************.**********.timecardmanager, PID: 2451
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isProxy()' on a null object reference
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.isProxyClass(Proxy.java:261)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveProperties(ObjectStreamClass.java:1016)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.isEnum(ObjectStreamClass.java:1040)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkAndGetTcObjectClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1341)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1788)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readContent(ObjectInputStream.java:707)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.discardData(ObjectInputStream.java:636)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1488)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:759)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.********************.**********.timecardmanager.MainActivity.sendToServer(MainActivity.java:158)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.********************.**********.timecardmanager.TimecardFragment$GetCardsTask.doInBackground(TimecardFragment.java:81)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.********************.**********.timecardmanager.TimecardFragment$GetCardsTask.doInBackground(TimecardFragment.java:1)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-20 14:38:16.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     ... 4 more
```

Thanks in advance.

edit: server side. run each time a new client connects on a new thread.

```
try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());

        TransferObject obj = (TransferObject) ois.readObject();

        switch(obj.command)
        {
            case "REQ":
                JavaTimecard[] javaCards = BullhornTools.getJavaCards(obj.getUser(), obj.getPassword());

                if(javaCards == null)
                {
                    obj.command = "ERR";
                    obj.args = BullhornTools.getError();
                    obj.setUser("");
                    obj.setPassword("");

                    oos.writeObject(obj);
                    oos.flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.command = "AKK";
                    obj.args = "";
                    obj.objects = new Object[javaCards.length];
                    obj.setUser("");
                    obj.setPassword("");

                    for(int i = 0; i < javaCards.length; i++)
                    {
                        obj.objects[i] = javaCards[i];
                    }

                    oos.writeObject(obj);
                    oos.flush();
                }

                break;



            case "SAVE":
                //TODO: Implement later
                break;
        }

        soc.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: and what is stored in `Object[] objects` ...

Comment: What's com.********************.**********.timecardmanager.MainActivity.sendToServer(MainActivity.java:158) ?

Comment: And what does the code at the other end look like? NB You needn't keep your `serialVersionUID` value a secret, it isn't a security breach.

Comment: @Selvin JavaTimecards

Comment: @TooManyEduardos just a blanked out package name. has personal info.

Comment: I dont care what the package name is...your crash report links to this line of code: MainActivity.sendToServer(MainActivity.java:158). What do you have there that is causing this crash?

Comment: @EJP I'll add it now.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos this: Object inputObject = ois.readObject();   //Error happens here.

Comment: Can you post lines of code before and after line 158 in MainActivity.java

Comment: So it seems then like your ois object is null

Comment: ois is not null(as NPE is from java.io.ObjectInputStream-ois) ... problem is with deserialization ... seems like this object is too compliacted/using classes which are not on android or some serialization proxy ..... any way ... just use json ...

Comment: What is the class `JavaTimeCard`? Why do we have to keep asking you to provide relevant information? Your question cannot be answered in its present form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to test it by serializing, storing in a file, and reading it back in. That worked fine, therefore I'm going to assume its an android thing. As Selvin said, just used JSON.

As for any possible lack of clearness, I apologize.